# Why did Kotlin JSR223 Scripting stop working when I upgraded to Kotlin 1.3.30

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In a project that uses the [`javax.script` scripting support added in 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support) in its unit tests, upgrading the Kotlin language version from 1.3.21 to 1.3.30 caused those tests to fail with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/scripting/compiler/plugin/ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.makeCompilerConfiguration(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:72)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.access$makeCompilerConfiguration(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$replCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:49)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$replCompiler$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:38)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getReplCompiler(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$localEvaluator$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine$localEvaluator$2.invoke(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:38)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getLocalEvaluator(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.getReplEvaluator(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.script.jsr223.KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.createState(KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngine.kt:59)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.createState$default(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:46)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.getCurrentState(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.nextCodeLine(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:59)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.eval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:31)
```

The relevant lines in `build.gradle` are:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other stuff ...
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:$kotlin_version"
}
```

where `ext.kotlin_version` is either `"1.3.21"` or `"1.3.30"`.

Why did this break, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It broke because JetBrains have refactored the scripting functionality into a plugin, and the dependencies required to successfully run Kotlin script through JSR223 have changed.

The relevant issue on the Kotlin bug tracker is [KT-30972](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30972), which was closed as a duplicate of [KT-30986](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30986).

The upshot is, you need to adjust the dependencies to include `kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable`.

```
dependencies {
    // ... other stuff ...
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 1):

the working version nowadays is simply:

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:${Deps.JetBrains.Kotlin.VERSION}")
}
```

which pulls in all necessary dependencies transitively.

Also the `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` File seems not to be necessary if doing so.